# Fourier sine and cosine series of these functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

What are the Fourier sine and cosine series of these functions: for $0 < x < \pi$:

1. $x$
2. $x(\pi − x)$
3. $e^{-\alpha x}$
4. a function which is 1 when $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2} $, -1 when $\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \pi $

Comment: It is just a matter of integrating the appropriate formula. What difficulty  are you encountering?

Comment: Have you looked at examples in your notes and/or textbook? If there is something you don't understand in these examples, you can present what you don't understand here and I'm sure somebody will help you out. Also, usually, people asking questions on this site show what they've already done while trying to solve a problem.

Comment: I checked the answers for 2 and 4 again and again but it is still not correct